# Test for systematic difference between two samples

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I would like to now if there is a significant difference in the two samples a & b. It is not important for me to know which way the difference is, just if there is one. The two samples can include outliers (way to big). So i would like the test not to give those outliers too much importance.

```r
a <- c(1022, 4518, 6470, 5969, 6721, 3924, 6408, 4581, 4528, 2790, 
    2290, 2551, 1542, 4926, 3533, 4560, 1595, 4388, 3226, 3983, 1508, 
    22, 1181, 3274, 5245, 3504, 2969, 3535, 1908, 4376, 2716, 3927, 
    3546, 546, 2730, 4659, 5008, 3576, 4266, 3508, 5941, 4280, 1385, 
    3984, 3639, 3637, 5525, 2849, 4106, 2388, 2375, 3222, 3360, 3758, 
    3155, 507, 276, 322, 204, 1519, 1439, 1267, 1447, 669, 311, 2643, 
    2408, 2454, 2251, 1492, 2193, 2668, 1512, 1897, 972, 1091, 1710, 
    2228, 1546, 1725, 1995, 2140, 1117, 1582, 1481, 0, 29, 554, 1276, 
    1207, 1745, 1407, 699, 921, 1220, 1151, 1263, 715, 1252, 3592, 
    3942, 3587, 2759, 3739, 2288, 2724, 1923, 196, 254, 1766, 3296, 
    2343, 3312, 3407, 3498, 3225, 3287, 5097, 2704, 3237, 2955, 2849, 
    3230, 3573, 2188, 3234, 2258, 2504, 2135, 1175, 2141, 1699, 1068, 
    4330, 2288, 3434, 2993, 2903, 2650, 3657, 1974, 1985, 702, 1407, 
    870, 1975, 1814, 953, 2230, 1642, 478, 69, 333, 166, 410, 295, 
    373, 671, 175, 534, 212, 393, 1732, 2082, 2855, 4262, 4238, 1930, 
    1356, 1397, 1200, 527, 826, 637, 2023, 3450, 850, 4124, 2597, 
    2067, 1755, 2620, 1483, 1646, 252, 950, 2302, 880, 3256, 16, 681, 
    816, 2282, 229, 58, 327, 4236, 926, 2202, 987, 3943, 2285, 1446, 
    1930, 1343, 296, 739, 91, 1040, 1083, 571, 359, 704, 470, 715, 35)

b <- c(2308, 1234, 948, 1069, 1096, 172, 2295, 1833, 925, 362, 1525, 
    1399, 926, 1075, 2614, 1810, 1693, 2130, 2004, 922, 949, 2282,   
    1179, 835, 1356, 1645, 2401, 3353, 1285, 1124, 2403, 1542, 1399, 
    45, 1839, 2557, 529, 320, 1487, 352, 1059, 1445, 2301, 3771, 2585, 
    927, 1470, 934, 2338, 2022, 2980, 1976, 1754, 1506, 1827, 2857, 
    1351, 2342, 631, 2228, 2057, 7178, 1611, 887, 1236, 535, 1093, 
    139, 809, 272, 1252, 1253, 204, 300, 819, 492, 395, 777, 1252, 
    775, 1320, 885, 829, 317, 532, 279, 221, 303, 613, 143, 314, 1856, 
    131, 2875, 2302, 3663, 1644, 1323, 1292, 2111, 691, 1689, 1535, 
    655, 1552, 2495, 2123, 2090, 1410, 2183, 4445, 1257, 1551, 2273, 
    1775, 2396, 1655, 1842, 1650, 665, 1737, 1038, 1881, 1607, 486, 
    459, 1160, 1644, 1785, 2535, 1080, 2348, 2485, 700, 2875, 3079, 
    1773, 3232, 2418, 2160, 2597, 2176, 2301, 2539, 3087, 3779, 4333, 
    2966, 2821, 3064, 2891, 2317, 2864, 2632, 1325, 0, 2765, 3567, 
    2822, 2115, 3037, 3251, 3830, 3602, 3775, 2963, 2228, 1668, 3620, 
    2240, 2326, 1857, 3301, 2259, 2338, 3365, 2243, 2734, 3320, 2286, 
    2731, 2766, 4035, 2481, 2301, 2559, 2656, 0, 2741, 2499, 2926, 
    3407, 3128, 1989, 2345, 3469, 2648, 2809, 2187, 2295, 2370, 2970, 
    2661, 1856, 2390, 0, 2075, 2464, 2497, 2040, 2022, 3867, 1750, 
    2328, 1430, 1848, 2591, 845, 2243, 2005, 2106, 2169, 2445, 2156, 
    2020, 2787, 2785, 4776, 3182, 723, 2016, 283, 1616, 1024, 1688, 
    2092, 1381, 1262, 1523, 1198, 1966, 2504, 3077, 1813, 1872, 1232, 
    2280, 2077, 1630, 2037, 1472, 1265, 1700, 1425, 1677, 1058, 1066, 
    1596, 1734, 392, 840, 774, 2124, 3270, 1451, 1106, 1171, 2636, 
    1586, 495, 650, 1303, 397, 1865, 1647, 1449, 704, 2136, 0, 533, 
    254, 283, 254, 566, 381, 383, 298, 254, 1019, 556, 70, 572, 254, 
    568, 758, 521, 439, 1537, 324, 515, 330, 469, 318, 951, 1189, 
    1031)
```

I think a Mann-Whitney-U Test is the right thing to do here.

```
wilcox.test(a, b)
Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  a and b
W = 37852, p-value = 0.004653
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Am i right about the assumption that this results means there is a "systematic" difference between the two samples (e.g. one sample is in general smaller than the other one). And since i am using the Mann-Whitney-U test i am just considering the ranks of the two samples and outliers do not get too much weight?

A Welch Two Sample t-test would consider the variance and thereby give the outliers more importance, right?

Comment: Try defining what a systematic difference is for you. For example, are different variances a systematic difference for you? If any difference is of interest, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Erik:  "if the majority in sample a is bigger than the majority in sample b". So what you think the mann-whitney-u-test will not answer me that question?